# English translation of Gerard Laumon's work on $\ell-$adic fourier transform

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

I'd like to know if there is an english translation of Laumon's "Transformation de Fourier, constantes d’´equations fonctionelles et conjecture de Weil". One can find the original paper in http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1987__65__131_0.pdf.

Thanks

Comment: write-up by Kedlaya  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210149.pdf

Comment: references  for https://math.uni.lu/nt/NT-Sem/Perverse-Sheaves-Program.pdf